# Does the English or the American rule prevail in Canada?

Tags: canada, common-law, australia, any-jurisdiction, costs

In English rule jurisdictions, the general principle is that loser of a case pays the costs on an indemnity basis. In American rule ones, the norm is that each side bears their own costs. Which prevails in Canada and other common law countries?

Answer (score 8):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

The general rule is that the substantially successful party is entitled to "costs" on a prescribed scale (e.g. [British Columbia](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/168_2009_05); [Manitoba](https://www.manitobacourts.mb.ca/pdf/tariff.pdf)) not full indemnity costs.